# access url helper generically in a generic view

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a generic table view that renders a single table for different controller view templates. The active record objects are stored as "record". I would like to know how I can access the record's url helper e.g. `post_path(post)` without knowing what the record is:

```
# views/generic_helpers/_table.html.erb
<tbody>
        <% table.collection.each do |record| %>
            <tr>
              <% table.columns.each do |column| %>
                <%= column.value(record) %>
              <% end %>
            </tr>
        <% end %>
        <% if table.can_edit? %>
            <tr>
              <%= link_to "Edit", record_path(record) %>
            </tr>
        <% end %>
    </tbody>
```

A record could be a Post active record object, a User active record object, etc. So where I say "record_path", it should be "user_path", "post_path", etc depending on the active record object. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Minor, but shouldn't your `link_to "Edit" record_path(record)` be `link_to "Edit" edit_record_path(record)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rails will try to infer the route from the type of ActiveRecord object, so you can avoid using the _url or _path helpers entirely. Assuming you have the routes defined for :posts:

```
resources :posts
```

Then you can do the following:

```
link_to "Show, @post
link_to "Edit", [:edit, @post]
```

So, generically:

```
link_to "Show", record
link "Edit", [:edit, record]
```